# how to compare a list of names in a table

Tags: protractor

My test scenario is to search for last name and expect whether all the names in the table are equal to the search value. I have a different function to search for the last name.

What i want now is to get all the names in the table and to test whether all the names have the same value. I want to use the below function in my page object and use it in the expect in the spec. How to do so?

I am confused how to use getText() and push them into an array and return the array so that i can use it in the expect

```
this.getAllBorrowerNamesInTable = function () {
    element.all(by.binding('row.borrowerName')).then(function (borrowerNames){
     });        
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `map()`, you can approach it by simply calling `getText()` on the `ElementArrayFinder` - the result of `element.all()` call:

```
this.getAllBorrowerNamesInTable = function () {
    return element.all(by.binding('row.borrowerName')).getText();
}
```

Then, you can assert the result to be equal to an array of strings:

```
expect(page.getAllBorrowerNamesInTable()).toEqual(["Borrower 1", "Borrower 2"]);
```

Comment: i didnt know that getText() will work in elementArrayFinder...Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [`map()` function](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to do the job:

```
this.getAllBorrowerNamesInTable = function () {
    return element.all(by.binding('row.borrowerName')).map(function(elem) {
        return elem.getText();
    )};
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript 'push' function to add every borrower name and then we can return that array;

```
this.getAllBorrowerNamesInTable = function () {
var names = [];
element.all(by.binding('row.borrowerName')).then(function (borrowerNames){
    borrowerNames.each(function(borrowerName) {
        borrowerName.getText().then(function(name) {
            names.push(name);
        });
    });
 });
 return names;        
};
```

Comment: this will pretty much return a null array. Because the names.push is happening asynchronously FYI